# How to use "attributes" field after "show timeseries where" command to filter parameters in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

When I filter time series fields when querying in Apache IoTDB, can I use `attributes` to filter after `show timeseries where` statement? Can anyone give an example on how to write this query statement in IoTDB?